# Signalr Test Project Not Working As Expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm trying to create a simple SignalR test project; however, it isn't behaving in the way that I believe it should.  I have a web site with the following code:

```
namespace SignalRTest3
{    
    public class MyHub1 : Hub
    {
        public void Hello(string message)
        {
            Clients.All.Hello();
            
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(SignalRTest3.Startup))]
namespace SignalRTest3
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);

            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

I've changed the Index page:

```
<body>
    <!-- HTML Content -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/SignalRTest.js"></script>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>SignalR Test</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

And the JS file referenced above is:

```
$(function () {
    // Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
    var hub = $.connection.MyHub1;

    // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
    hub.client.Hello = function (message) {

        alert(message);
    };

    hub.start();
});
```

So, the intention is that, when receiving a notification, the site will display an alert.  To trigger this, I have a console app:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Message: ");
        string message = Console.ReadLine();

        HubConnection connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:4035/");
        IHubProxy hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub1");
        connection.Start().Wait();
        hub.Invoke<string>("Hello", message).Wait();            
    }
}
```

So I type a message, and can see that the code in the hub fires, but it looks like there's something wrong with the wiring between the javascript and the hub; please can someone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: change method signatures and `hub.start` as per JPThorne's suggestion

EDIT: tried using CORS, but to no avail

It looks like the problem may be with the proxy; I'm getting the following output in the F12 console window:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'MyHub1' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (VM456 SignalRTest.js:3)
    at c (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21)
    at HTMLDocument.q (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21) (anonymous) @ VM456 SignalRTest.js:3 c @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21 fireWith @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21 ready @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21 q @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21
```

UPDATE:

Thanks to help from JPThorne, I finally tracked it down to the BundleConfig file; mine looked like this:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
// Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
// ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
            "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
          "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
          "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
          "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
          "~/Content/site.css"));
```

As best I can gather, the regex used for {version} on `~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js` was also picking up the SignalR scripts too early!

Comment: A quick question, both these codes are in same project or two different project because IMO one seems to be a console based application and another a web based. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes - separate applications.  Console app to send the message, and a web app to display it

Comment: It's important that you also allow CORS. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client

Comment: I thought CORS was only relevant when you were going cross-domain?

Comment: @Tester has already mentioned in his comment to enable CORS that way you can send messages from console app to web app. Since you are in a development phase and the project have different port number you will have to implement CORS in your current application. If you are planning to host them in a single domain (I assume you will) then CORS is not necessary continue with what you are working and test them on LIVE site.

Comment: I have tried using CORS (see edited question).  I'm not completely sure what was meant by a LIVE site with relation to a console app, but I have tried both hosting this in IIS as a web site, and setting the port to 80; neither made any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to start the hub on the client side. Well, that's what works for us. You could try this:

```
$.connection.hub
    .start()
    .done(function() { console.log("Hub started"); })
    .fail(function() { console.log("Error: could not connect"); });
```

In addition, I've found the following listeners to be handy:

```
$.connection.hub.connectionSlow(function() {
    console.log("We are currently experiencing difficulties with the connection.");
});

$.connection.hub.error(function (error) {
    console.log("SignalR error: ", error);
});
```

UPDATE #1:
I would change `Clients.All.hello();` on your server to be `Clients.All.hello(message);`

and then on the FE change `hub.client.Hello = function (name, message)` to `hub.client.Hello = function (message)`

UPDATE #2:
Add : 
`[HubName("MyHub1")]` above `public class MyHub1 : Hub`

UPDATE #3:

Ok so I tried your version, and there's a few problems actually.

1. Don't call start like this: `hub.start();` call it like this:  `$.connection.hub.start();`
2. You might want to upgrade to the latest version of jquery.
3. Make sure you're referencing jquery above your SignalRTest.js - that's why you get that 'cannot read property of undefined' error above.

Comment: It would appear that, while this may be correct, it's not the whole answer (still not getting the alert).

Comment: Ok, so looking at your code again I'm seeing:

public void Hello(string message) and 

hub.client.Hello = function (name, message) {

so... you aren't using the first string message - you aren't passing it through. And on the front-end script you have an additional name param. 

Check my updated answer. The params have to match up.

Comment: Tried that.  I even tried playing with the case of the method (Hello/hello), but no dice.

Comment: @pm_2 yeah so as the commenters above mentioned - you would also probably need to enable cors. In my solution I have my hub in a class library which is then referenced by my web project which has the FE js. You could also try doing that.

Comment: I tried enabling CORS (as detailed above).  Sorry, I'm unsure what "FE js" is?

Comment: Sorry it's front end Javascript. Have you tried having the hub in the web project as a reference to a class library? Or just straight in the project?

Comment: The hub class is inside the web project

Comment: @pm_2 updated answer again. I have a working version I could send to you if you like?

Comment: JQuery is referenced above signalrtest.js - although now you've said that, I wonder if we're talking about the same thing when we say "above".  I pre-empted changing hub to $.connection... and it made not difference.  I've also updated JQuery to 3.1.1, but all to no avail.

Comment: Thanks - I'm happy to take a working version: that way I can identify the difference and update the question with whichever daft thing I've missed

Comment: @pm_2 righto, yeah at this point it is clearly something very small that's off. Here is a link to the zip on dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/upo8ks30txjd6c2/SignalRTest.zip?dl=0# hope it works for you. The relevant files are Program.cs in the console project; MyHub1, Startup, BundleConfig, SignalRTest.js and _Layout.cshtml in the webproject. I run the webproject, detach the debugger, and then run the console app.

Comment: Many thanks for this - I finally got to the bottom of it (updating question to point out the offending line)

Comment: Glad we finally got it sorted!